# Testing an ip address with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to test the following strings of ip addresses for validity, such as:

```
1.1.1.1/8
15.10.30.100/16
100.10.10.44/24
198.30.20.30/32
```

and I have the following regex that tests whether each item of ip:

```
 !/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]\/\/(/^\d+)/ig?)$/.test(item.trim())
```

But im not sure how about the part where there is a forward slash followed by a number such as `/24`, `/32`... which is `\/\/(/^\d+)/ig`. Could anybody point what i did wrong here?

Comment: Apart from the slashes, the part that reads `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?` will match two- and three-digit numbers that start with 0 like `000`---not sure if you want that.

Answer (score 2):

I did not check the error in your regex but I here's a working one

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|[0-2]?[0-4]?[0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|[0-2]?[0-4]?[0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))(?:\/(?:3[0-2]|[1-2]?[0-9])|$)$
```

[Test it here](http://regexr.com/3goku)

The regex should check allocation blocks from 0 to 32 and IP4 without it.

If you want to check specific allocation blocks you should use this one

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|[0-2]?[0-4]?[0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|[0-2]?[0-4]?[0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))(?:\/(?:8|16|24|32)|$)
```

and filtering blocks inside the last nested non-capturing group `(?:8|16|24|32)`

[Test it here](http://regexr.com/3gol1)

Comment: Non capture group is `(?:...)`, not `(:?...)` that means a capture group that begins with an optional `:`.

Comment: `(?:3[0-2]|[1-2][0-9]|[0-9])` can be shortened to `(?:3[0-2]|[1-2]?[0-9])`

Comment: @WillBarnwell, yes, I had that at some point but changed it while testing something; Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1):

You must have had trouble pasting the regex from an online regex tester to the JS code. However, there are issues here: 1) you have `\/\/` that requires `//` to appear in the string, 2) you added `^` anchor close to the end of the pattern (and since it requires the start of string position, it prevented your regex from matching). Besides, no need for `g` and `i` modifiers, you only test the whole string against the pattern that has no letters in it.

Use

```
/^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\/(?:[12]?\d|3[0-2])$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5pPE5v/2).

In JS, you may build the pattern dynamically for better readability:

```js
var octet = "(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
var rx = new RegExp("^" + octet + "(?:\\." + octet + "){3}/(?:[12]?\\d|3[0-2])$");
var strs = [ "1.1.1.1/8", "15.10.30.100/16", "100.10.10.44/24", "198.30.20.30/32", "1.1.1.1/0", "1.1.1.1/32", "1.1.1.1/33"];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` - an octet pattern, `0` to `255`
- `(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}`  - 3 occurrences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` - an octet pattern
- `\/` - a slash
- `(?:[12]?\d|3[0-2])` - an opptional `1` or `2` followed with any digit (`0` to `29`, matched with `[12]?\d`), or `3` followed with digits from `0` to `2` (`30` to `32`)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Subnet mask can't be more than 32.

Comment: @Toto If you mean the number after `/` can be from `1` to `32` the `\\d+` must be replaced with `(?:[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[0-2])`.

Comment: it should actually be switched to `(?:[12]?\\d|3[0-2])`. `/0` to `/32` are valid subnet masks in CIDR notation

Comment: @WillBarnwell Thank you for the correction. I added that to the answer with more test cases and explanation.